# JavaScript - change color of Google Map marker based on data

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have some google map markers `markers` displayed on google map in browser. I need to change the color of the marker based on some input data every few seconds. The color of the google map marker can be changed via `fillColor`,   `strokeColor` properties of the marker (Symbol).

### places

```
 let places = [ 
    { name: "place1", placeId: 1, lat:19.29 , long: 72.85},
    { name: "place2", placeId: 2, lat:19.27 , long: 72.88},
];
```

The data that need use to change the marker color, is something like below, with the marker color need to be changed based on `val` field. Note that the `placeId` property is same across `data` and `places`.

### data

```
 let data = [ 
    { time: "11/22/16 10:00:00", placeId: 1, val: 33},
    { time: "11/22/16 10:00:10", placeId: 1, val: 12},
    { time: "11/22/16 10:00:30", placeId: 1, val: 78},
    { time: "11/22/16 10:00:00", placeId: 2, val: 7},
    { time: "11/22/16 10:00:10", placeId: 2, val: 28},
    { time: "11/22/16 10:00:20", placeId: 2, val: 94},
    { time: "11/22/16 10:00:30", placeId: 2, val: 46},
];
```

As you see the color for markers for `placeId` 1 & 2 changes with time, ie. every 10 minutes. I need to map this change in every 10minutes by changing the color of the markers every 2 seconds.

So in my hypothetical `app.js` I start with something like below

### app.js

```
# create map and append to div #map
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 12});
# add markers
for(let place of places){
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place.lat, place.long);
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: { path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 2,
                fillColor: `Crimson`,
                strokeColor: `Crimson`                          
             }
});
```

At this point I have a map with two markers. Now I need to change the color of these markers every 2 seconds based on 'val`.

- At t = 0s, color each marker based on `val` at `11/22/16 10:00:00`
- At t = 2s, color each marker based on `val` at`11/22/16 10:00:10`
- At t = 4s, color each marker based on `val` at `11/22/16 10:00:20`
- At t = 8s, color each marker based on `val` at `11/22/16 10:00:30`

If val is not present for a particular time record, fall back default colors

Here is where I'm stuck, should I use something like a setInterval every 2s to redraw the markers with appropriate colors based on the value every 2 seconds?

Also is there a way to select the colors from a certain color palette (like `terrain.gradient` in R ) set the color based on `val` ?

### jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t9mv87fs/15/)